# How to start application in android system directly from the browser?

Tags: android

Is it possible and if yes, how to start application directly from email, or browser.

What I want to achieve:
user receives in email some activation link, clicks it and he is redirected to app, possibly with some Extras put into intent.

Thanks in advance,
Patryk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean the browser in your phone? Yes it's totally possible with a caveat that the app in question has to support such intent. For example if in your browser you click `mailto` link it will start the email app. [More on intents and intent filters here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)